# Наполнение базы в MongoDB

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, mongodb

> Объясните, пожалуйста, мне не удается посмотреть данные базы или заполнить ее? По алгоритму коллекция должна заполнится 10000 документов. В базе написано, что документов 700. А по факту вижу только 44.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';


(async () => {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });

    const collection = client.db('usersdb').collection('users');

     for(let i = 0; i<=10000; i++){
       await collection.insertOne({name:randomName(), score:i});
     }
     console.log('Generating dump data is done');

    await collection.createIndex({score:1});
     await collection.createIndex({name:1,score:1}); 
    await collection.dropIndex({score:1});
    await collection.dropIndex({name:1,score:1});
  
    let res = await collection.find({name:'a'}).explain();
    console.log(res);


})().catch(error => console.log(error));

async function randomName(){
  return (Math.random()+1).toString(36).substring(2);
}
```

Comment: вы подключаетесь в коде к `usersdb.users`, на скрине у вас `usersdb2.users2`. Вы заполняете рандомными именами, а выборку делаете на `{name:'a'}`.

Comment: и причем тут C#?

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. Добавлен второй скрин c нужным количеством 10k. Только как посмотреть их? Доступно  лишь 15.

Comment: В смысле как посмотреть? У вас же прямо в программе, где вы смотрите общее количество, есть фильтрация и постраничный вывод.